phase PSD of complex additive white gaussian noise
what is the power spectral density (PSD) shape of the phase of complex additive white gaussian noise (AWGN), $n(t)=n_I(t)+jn_q(t)=r(t)e^{j\phi_n(t)}$, I could not find a source specifying the PSD shape of $\phi_n(t)$, I know its distribution is uniform. I have tried the following Python code to deduce the PSD shape, and found the result to vary based on if the phase is wrapped or unwrapped, the unwrapped case is shaped noise, with high power concentrated at lower frequencies, while the wrapped one seems white as shown, which one is correct. It is important for my application to know the shape of the spectrum, as this signal will be manipulated by phase locking loop.
What is also confusing is, when we look at the AWGN in the complex plane, it constitutes a noisy cloud around the mean of the signal, it does not show a wandering random walk phase, so does it mean the unwrapped phase does not represent that case properly?
Python code:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import signal

# Parameters
sigma_I = 1/np.sqrt(2)
sigma_Q = 1/np.sqrt(2)
sigma_noise=np.sqrt((sigma_I**2)+(sigma_Q**2))
fs = 1  # Sampling frequency
N = 1000000  # Number of samples

# Generate AWGN
i = np.random.normal(0, sigma_I, N)
q = np.random.normal(0, sigma_Q, N)
noise = i + 1j*q  # Complex noise

# Decompose into amplitude and phase noise
amplitude_noise = np.abs(noise)
phase_noise_unwrapped = np.unwrap(np.angle(noise))
phase_noise_wrapped = np.angle(noise)

# Calculate PSD using Welch's method
f_I, psd_I = signal.welch(i, fs, nperseg=1024, return_onesided=True)
f_Q, psd_Q = signal.welch(q, fs, nperseg=1024, return_onesided=True)

f_phase, psd_phase_unwrap = signal.welch(phase_noise_unwrapped, fs, nperseg=1024)
f_phase, psd_phase_wrapped = signal.welch(phase_noise_wrapped, fs, nperseg=1024)

expected_amp_psd_I=np.ones(len(f_I))*(sigma_I**2)*(1/fs)*2

expected_amp_psd_Q=np.ones(len(f_Q))*(sigma_Q**2)*(1/fs)*2


# Plot the PSDs
plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
plt.plot(f_I, psd_I, label='I- Noise PSD')
plt.plot(f_Q, psd_Q, label='Q- Noise PSD')
plt.plot(f_I, expected_amp_psd_I, label='Expected I- Noise PSD')
plt.plot(f_Q, expected_amp_psd_Q, label='Expected Q- Noise PSD')
plt.xlabel('Frequency [Hz]')
plt.ylabel('PSD (Amplitude Noise) [V**2/Hz]')
plt.title('Amplitude Noise PSD')
plt.grid(True)
plt.legend()
plt.show()

plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
plt.semilogy(f_phase, psd_phase_unwrap, label='Phase Noise PSD w unwrap', color='orange')
plt.semilogy(f_phase, psd_phase_wrapped, label='Phase Noise PSD wo unwrap', color='blue')

plt.xlabel('Frequency [Hz]')
plt.ylabel('PSD (Phase Noise) ')
plt.title('Phase Noise PSD')
plt.grid(True)
plt.legend()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()



Unwrapping the phase would seem to potentially violate the uniform distribution assumption since the phase is uniformly distributed in $\left[ -\pi,\pi\right]$. IID noise has an autocovariance sequence that is a delta, so the spectrum should be flat.

@Baddioes Thanks for your reply, can you provide a reference that the PSD of that phase is white, additionally what is the formula to predict its PSD value given the I & Q noise variances.

IID noise with zero mean and finite variance is white, which is what you have. For a zero mean process, the power is the variance.

The SNR due to additive white Gaussian noise has half of its power in the phase distribution and half in the amplitude distribution. A white noise distribution has a constant power spectral density in frequency (hence the name "white").
The phase noise of a signal is not the angle of the complex noise that is added as the OP has done, but is the angle of the signal plus noise, and to be anywhere near realistic, this should be done with a small angle as follows:
# Generate AWGN
i = np.random.normal(0, sigma_I, N)
q = np.random.normal(0, sigma_Q, N)
noise = i + 1j*q  # Complex noise

snr = 20

sig_and_noise = 1 + 10**(snr/20) * noise

ph_noise = np.angle(sig_and_noise)

A small angle is appropriate for all typical applications of phase noise as introduced by practical oscillators (where the phase noise is typically 10s of dB's below the carrier). We would encounter large angle phase under applications of phase modulation, not phase noise. Further, the unwrap function for a white noise process is not very meaningful given the phase from sample to sample is completely independent (the experimental results of a white noise process in time is also white in frequency).
Assuming small angles, the magnitude of the spectrum is directly proportional to phase (I show this intuitively from the graphic below). Therefore the phase power spectral density for a white noise process is also white (constant versus frequency).

In this plot I am depicting a carrier frequency normalized to 1 (so 0 dB), with a phase error shown as a quadrature phasor representing the total rms phase error as a magnitude quantity. Given the small angle approximation, this rms magnitude is approximately the rms phase itself, and thus the total power due to phase noise would be the magnitude squared resulting in $20log_{10}(\theta)$ dBc (as dB below the carrier).  Given the time domain signal producing this phase noise is white, the frequency spectrum is constant and this rms phase noise would be the the total noise power integrated over all frequencies. Given the impossibility of having a convergent result in this case (the typical issue with "white noise") in practice we would work with a noise density (dBc/Hz) and define a range of frequencies of interest to us (within our system bandwidth) in which we assume over that range that the noise power is white, and thus when we integrate over that range specifically we converge to the rms phase noise I describe here.

Do you mean half is in the “in-phase” and half is in the “quadrature” portions?

@Baddioes No I meant half the power is in the AM and half is in the PM (but your statement is true as well).  Complex AWGN when added to a single tone carrier results in AM noise and PM noise (visualize it on a complex plane where the carrier is a phasor of magnitude 1 and angle 0 and the decomposition into AM and PM components is very clear).

I should fix my opening paragraph to be clearer that I am referring to the noise imparted onto a signal not the noise itself.

Thank you for your answer, I really missed that what matters is the phase of signal added to noise not the noise only.

@MohamedOsama Thanks Mohamed. My opening statement initially wasn't clear about that either so I fixed that thanks to Baddios' comment.  The IQ (complex) visualizations are immensely helpful once you get used to them. Everything is relative to the carrier (as if we flashed a strobe light on the IQ trajectory at the rate of the carrier) causing it to be the phasor at magnitude 1 and angle 0.   (See this answer where I use that appoach to understand or explain AM and PM modulation more generally: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/61670/21048

@DanBoschen is there a way to obtain the PSD of the theta without using that small signal approximation? in other words, if I have a low SNR values and I know the sigma of in phase and quadrature noise, how to predict the PSD level of the theta without using that approximation?  I think it follows  arctan(quadrature noise / (symbol amplitude + in phase noise) ) how to continue?

If you have a signal in mind other than it being the reference 1 angle 0 as I did in my answer, then you can determine the phase noise for each sample by measuring the phase of your signal+noise (as I did in my last line) and then subtracting that from the phase of your signal.  The difference is the noise. You can't do what you last wrote as that assumes the signal is always aligned with I which may not be the case. Simply take the real and imaginary components of the complex addition of your signal to the noise and use that as I and Q to compute the phase.

For that you can use the four quadrant arctan: np.atan2(Q, I), or np.angle(signal+noise) as I have done. And then subtract the angle of the signal determined using np.angle(signal), or atan2(Q_sig, I_sig)
